# Django-Import-Export is not showing up in Admin interface GUI

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have been following the instructions to get the django-import-export http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ library to work with my models (for importing Products into my Product model). The import/export commands don't to appear on the admin GUI.

```
from import_export import resources
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product, Category
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportMixin, ExportMixin, ImportExportMixin

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource

admin.site.register(Category)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to register your `ProductAdmin`. Change this:

```
admin.site.register(Product)
```

To this:

```
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```